# undefined action() in phpunit

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class MemberRegTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testExample()
    {
       $response = $this->call('GET', '/addmember');
      $response = $this->action('GET', 'MemberController@addmember');

    }
}
```

After testing gives me error

> Error: Call to undefined method Tests\Feature\MemberRegTest::action()

What i do wrong?

Comment: Does MemberRegTest or TestCase or any other parent contain the function action()?

Comment: at tutorials TestCase should have this function

Comment: Which tutorials are you following?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an `action` method inside `TestCase` back to Laravel 4.x. This method has been replaced for new ones in different classes and packages. (You can confirm this reviewing the Laravel 5.6 [TestCase class](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.html))

For the latest versions of Laravel, If you are trying to test a [HTTP Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/http-tests)  you could do:

```php
    $response = $this->json('GET', 'api/addmember');
    $response->assertStatus(200) // or whatever you want to assert.
```

Now if you want to do browser tests, you should use the official [Laravel Dusk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/dusk). This package has very cool and useful methods to simulate user interactions with your site, as easy as  this:

```php
    $this->browse(function ($browser) use ($user) {
        $browser->visit('/login')
                ->type('email', $user->email)
                ->type('password', 'secret')
                ->press('Login')
                ->assertPathIs('/home');
```