# Laravel 8: From a TestCase, how to give route's data to the method of a controller?

Tags: laravel

I have a class `ExampleTest extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` that contains a test which must call a controller function thanks to a HTTP GET method. The code below shows the GET in the test:

```
/**
 * @dataProvider provideTakePlaceData
 */
public function takePlace($project, $pro)
{
    $response = $this->action('get', 'ControllerUserProject@takePlace');
    $this->assertSame($project->getStatus(), Projet::STATE_TO_BE_REPLIED);
}
```

My controller `ControllerUserProject` indeed contains the method `takePlace`:

```
class ControllerUserProject extends App\Http\Controllers\Controller
{
    public function takePlace(Request $request, $project_id, $pro_id)
    {
        
    }
}
```

My question is: in the official documentation of Laravel 8, I don't find any information about the function `$this->action` that I use in my test function: how can I pass the `$project_id, $pro_id` that my controller's function requires?

Comment: any reason to not extend Laravel's TestCase class? that is what the testing documentation would be referring to

Comment: Why are you using functions if they aren't documented and don't do what you need? There are well documented functions that do what you want. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests

Comment: @lagbox the documentation actually extends from PPHUnit: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/testing

Comment: @miken32 I've seen `$this->action` on Stackoverflow. I don't want to test an HTTP request. I just want to do a test, by executing a method from my controller. The execution is HTTP.

Comment: This method doesn't exist anymore: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49372467/undefined-action-in-phpunit . I've closed my question.